# Can a Capacitance Multiplier be used with high voltage outputs?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, filter, power-electronics

I am designing an SMPS which two output voltages of 5kV and 2.5kV. My transformer is split into four equal sections, each feeding a FB multiplier, connected in series to form the final voltages. Output powers are 50W and 500W respectively.

The output voltage ripple on output 2 (2.5kV) is not of particular importance, however the ripple on output 1 (5kV) needs to be a maximum of 50mV. I have been looking into passive RC filters (LC filters would be too large) and I don't think I will achieve the attenuation I require with this alone.

I have been looking at regulating stages on the secondary side, such as series and shunt regulators for example.

My question is, could one possibly employ an emitter follower capacitance multiplier to attenuate power supply output ripple, when voltages are this large? I assume the BJT will not see the entire voltage, and it is possible but I am skeptical. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why would the answer be any different from "pore through the datasheets of the discrete parts you intend to use, and see if you're violating any of the conditions for use"?

Comment: Simulate the problem.